# How the super function works in java?

Tags: java, oop, decorator

Here is a code snippet from the head first design patterns book:

```
public class LowerCaseInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    public LowerCaseInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        int c = super.read();
        return (c == -1 ? c : Character.toLowerCase((char)c));
    }

    public int read(byte[] b, int offset, int len) throws IOException {
        int result = super.read(b, offset, len);
        for (int i = offset; i < offset+result; i++) {
            b[i] = (byte)Character.toLowerCase((char)b[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

There is another toy example in the same chapter:

```
public class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator {
    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }

    public double cost() {
        return .20 + beverage.cost();
    }
}
```

These two are quite similar except that the Macha class has a concrete object inside that it initialize and use, while the LowerCaseInputStream class initializes an InputStream object by `super(in)` and later seems to make use of this object by using the `super.read()` function.

I am a bit confused about how the super function works here. In the Mocha example, it's very clear that it wraps a beverage object inside and calls its methods and modifies the results, while in the LowerCaseInputStream class it's not straight-forward how the behavior modification happened.

Comment: It calls the constructor of the inherited class.

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html ?

Comment: Is the question about `super` only or is something unclear about inheritance vs. decoration as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case `super` refers to the constructor in the base class `FilterInputStream`. If the constructor of a parent class has argument, any class that extends it must explicitly call the appropriate constructor using `super`. If the base class simply has a no-argument constructor the `super` is supplied implicitly by Java.

In the second case, `FilterInputStream` `read` method has been overloaded by `LowerCaseInputStream`. This means that any call to `LowerCaseInputStream.read()` would go to its implementation. So for `LowerCaseInputStream` to call the `read` implementation in `FilterInputStream` (to get the standard behavior) it must reference `super` otherwise it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok, I see, an abstract class can contain static methods.

Comment: @qed static methods have nothing to do with that, in fact there is no `super` for static methods. The text might be misunderstood but is still correct in its meaning: `LowerCaseInputStream.read()` would mean the instance method `read()` as implemented by class `LowerCaseInputStream`. Whether a class is abstract or not is also not relevant if there is a super implementation.

Comment: You mean there is a `super` method implemented in FilterInputStream?

Comment: No, `super` is a Java keyword that provides a reference to the base class. As I state, in the first case it references the parent class' constructor. In the second, it allows for invocation of the parent class' method (read) which has been overridden and is therefore not accessible any other way. Please read the docs in the provided links.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `super` exists to give child classes access to their parent classes and their exposed public members. That being said:

1. `super(in)`: Calls the superclass's constructor, passing in the stream as an argument
2. `super.read()`: Calls the superclass's `read` method

Answer (score 0):

`super` keyword means parent, in this case `FilterInputStream`

```
//this invoke parent's constructor like `FilterInputStream(in)`
super(in);

//this invoke parent's read() method
super.read();
```

Learn basic Java Programming first well and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

`super()` in this case is just a keyword that allows you to call the constructor of the superclass (hence the name). You can call other functions using `super.function()` too.

Example,

```
public class A
{
     protected String myName;

     public A(String name)
     {
         this.myName = name;
     }

     public void print(String input)
     {
         System.out.println("" + input);
     }
}

public class B extends A
{
     public B(String name)
     {
         super(name); //calls A(String name) constructor above
     }

     @Override
     public void print(String input)
     {
         if(input == null || "".equals(input))
         {
             System.out.println(this.myName);
         }
         else
         {
             super.print(input); //calls A.print(String input)
         }
     }
}

public class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         B b = new B("qed");
         b.print(null); //prints 'qed'
     }
}
```

Comment: The `super.print()` example is not really clear and meaningful, since you'd not need the super keyword in that case and thus some might get confused.

Comment: @Thomas reasonable criticism, changed it a bit and hope I made it better